# Stuck in javascript variables closures

Tags: javascript

I just wanted to assign position.coords.latitude and longitude to lat and lon vars but it seems that I am missing something because Console always says lat lon to be undefined.

```
function init() 
{
    var lat;
    var lon;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
       {
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          lon = position.coords.longitude;     
       });
    }

    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lon);

}
```

Comment: Is getCurrentPosition executed asynchronous? (setTimeout / setInterval / AJAX)

Comment: Yes Asynchronous. Sorry for being noob but how can I make it Sync ?

Comment: When there is no parameter for that: There is no way except modifying the script. But probably this is a third-party library, right?

Comment: @AssadUllah: You don't want to make it synchronous. You should simply learn to work with asynchronous code. This means all code that relies on the response is called from the callback function. If needed, you can have `init()` accept a function as an argument, and have the callback call that function, and pass `lat` and `lon` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you define variables with `var` like you do at first, their values are undefined. Now when you call the `getCurrentPosition` function, it's probably asynchronous, which means that `console.logs` are called before you actually assign them any values. Try the following change

```
function init() 
{
    var lat;
    var lon;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
       {
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          lon = position.coords.longitude;  

          // Log them in the callback function
          console.log(lat);
          console.log(lon);  
       });
    }

}
```

Since you want to execute your actual code after you have the coords, here's how you could change your init function to accommodate asynchronous architecture.

```
// New function argument callbackFn - the function to call after 
// coords are loaded
function init(callbackFn) 
{
    // Removed local variables, no need for them here

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
       {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var lon = position.coords.longitude;  

          // This will be logged after the async call completes, probably after 
          // the console.log call below
          console.log("finished async call");

          // Execute the callback with coords
          callbackFn(lat, lon);
       });
    }

    // This will be called as soon as JS steps over previous lines, 
    // but before the asynchronous request has completed
    console.log("finished init");
}
```

Let's pretend your actual program begins when you execute a function called start with latitude and longitude. In that case, you would use the following to start your program:

```
function start(latitude, longitude) {
    // ... SNIP ... DO SOMETHING COOL
}

init(start);
```

Comment: Yes the function getCurrentPosition is Async but what I wanted to achieve is to assign the coordinates to lat and lon variables so I can use them afterwards

Comment: @AssadUllah asynchronous architecture is one of Javascripts fundamental ideas, trying to force it into synchronous execution is a bad-bad idea, so you always have to use callback functions. Updated the answer with example how you could do it.

Comment: @AssadUllah if you want, you can also write the variables as global, by changing `var lat` to `window.lat` (or just `lat`, but I suggest using `window` to prevent confusion). Keep in mind though, you STILL can't use them before the asynchronous callback has returned, so you should still have something along the lines I showed.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is asynchronous, so it wont have executed by the time you try writing to the console.

Try moving you console writes into the callback function:

```
function init() 
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
       {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var lon = position.coords.longitude;   

          console.log(lat);
          console.log(lon);
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the function getCurrentPosition is Async but what I wanted to achieve is to assign the coordinates to lat and lon variables so I can use them afterwards

Comment: That's fine, just declare lat and lon at global scope and assign their values in the callback. You'll probably need to bootstrap any further logic from the callback method - maybe have it call a method called handleGeolocation() or something similar.